# PHP flush server response via "proxy" server

Tags: php, http

I have a "proxy" server (A) running Apache/PHP requesting another server (B) running Apache/PHP using `file_get_contents`. When a user requests server A it requests server B. The request at server B needs up to two minutes to complete, so it responds very early with a waiting animation followed by a PHP `flush()`, sth. like this:

```
User       --->   Server A (a.php)             --->   Server B (b.php)
                  - file_get_contents to B            - flush after 1s
                  - nothing happens after 1s          - response end after 2m 
waits 2m   <---
```

The problem I have now is that this early flush from B is not "mirrored" by A. So the user has to wait the full time before seeing the final response. When I call server B directly it shows the waiting animation after 1 second.

**Minimal example code for "a.php":**

```
<?php
$stream_context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    )
));

echo file_get_contents('http://1.2.3.4/b.php', false, $stream_context);
?>
```

**Minimal example code for "b.php":**

```
<?php
echo 'Loading...';
flush();

// Long operation
sleep(60);

echo 'Result';
?>
```

**Q:**
Is there a way to get server A to "mirror" the early `flush` from server B, sending the exact flushed result from server B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use fopen/fread instead file_get_contents.
Then you can flush between your reads

Something like this:

```
<?php
$stream_context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    )
));

$fp = fopen('http://1.2.3.4/b.php', 'r', false, $context);
while (!feof($fp)) {
  echo fread($fp, 8192);
  flush();
}
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Comment: How exactly would I do that in a.php?

Comment: @migg, helps this you?

Comment: Thanks that helps. But what I read from the documentation this would possibly only flush part of my early flush, wouldn't it? Say the early flush has 12kbytes, then it would flush the first 8192 bytes and then wait for the rest?

Comment: Use less buffer for reading, for example `fread($fp, 1);` for flush each received byte immediately